# Configuring Interface Builder's new WKWebView object

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode8, wkwebview

As some of you may have noticed, Apple recently implemented the WKWebView (from WebKit) as an object in the Interface Builder; however, I am having difficulty with properly implementing it. I am still able to implement it by code, but implementing it via the Interface Builder has proven to be a bit of a pain.

The WKWebView appears blank on launch, and although the NSTextField appears to work when configured, the WKWebView continues to remain blank and doesn't even call upon `didStartProvisionalNavigation`, `didCommit` or `didFinish` when implemented (whereas, when done programatically, this continues to work).

**Interface Builder Screenshot**
[image: Interface Builder Screenshot]

**Interface Builder Menu Options**
[image: Interface Builder Menu Options]

**Note:** *I did attempt to implement it using the WebConfiguration as well, but no luck either. Now I'm just trying to keep the code as simplistic as possible to get a better understanding as to why this is not working.*

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Configure Window Appearance
        window!.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window!.isMovableByWindowBackground  = true
        window!.title = ""
        window!.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    let myURL = "https://google.com"

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var pageTitle: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load Homepage URL in WebView
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: myURL)!))

    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I hadn't noticed that they had finally provided WKWebView as a library object. Are you getting any error messages in the console on launch? What's the actual issue - is it just that the url doesn't load?

Comment: @matt No error messages, nothing. If I put a print statement in the viewDidLoad, it will return a message – but when putting a print statement in any of the WKNavigationDelegate's functions, there is no response. Quite strange, but awesome that they finally added it to the IB.

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem. I tried `self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://www.google.com")!))` in `viewDidLoad` and the web page loaded. Can you explain, as if I were not too bright, what the problem is?

Comment: Also I set the view controller as the web view's `navigationDelegate` in IB, and the delegate method `decidePolicy` is called just fine. — Voting to close this question as being unreproducible.

Comment: By the way, I was hoping that this would mean they had supplied WKWebView as a library object on iOS too. It doesn't. :(

Comment: Also strange how they'd include it as a macOS-exclusive object. As for the issue, still no luck. Will try creating a new project and starting from scratch I suppose.

Comment: Do you need me to send you a working project? Happy to do so. I can't imagine what the problem is with yours... Your screen shots are very complete and would seem to rule out any accidental misconfiguration.

Comment: After lots and lots of debugging, it seems that the App Sandbox entitlement was the issue. All I had was: `com.apple.security.network.server` set to `YES` and `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` set to `YES`. As soon as I removed the two Booleans and removed the entitlements file altogether, the WKWebView loaded without issue. This is very problematic, however, because the App Sandbox is a requirement for submitting to the Mac App Store...

Comment: That is likely to be useful info, so I recommend you answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, the WKWebView refuses to become active while there is an entitlements file in your project. In my case, I had the App Sandbox enabled with the following settings:

- `com.apple.security.network.server` – `YES`
- `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` – `YES`

Once deleting the entitlements file and removing it entirely from the project, the WKWebView began to work again.